# Primeng pTooltip loop

Tags: angular, tooltip, primeng

I try to display a list of string in a pTooltip with an ngFor.

```
<div pTooltip="Liste: <span *ngFor='let code of {{codes}}'>{{code}}</span>" [escape]="false"></div>
```

or

```
<div pTooltip="Liste: <ng-template ngFor let-code [ngForOf]="codes"><span>{{code}}</span></ng-template>" [escape]="false"></div>
```

Thinking with [escape]="false" will be ok but i have nothing.

Anyone have an idea please ?

Thank you

Comment: Check my answer , if this is something you are looking for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can show HTML content in pTooltip by setting  `[escape]="false"` and using property binding with pTooltip like this way `[pTooltip]`. 
I have used `<span>` tag in this example , you can also use `<ul>` to show a list of strings.

Here is the full working code :

**Component.ts file :**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app/app.template.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  isDisabled = false;
  isTooltipDisabled = false;
  codes:any[] = ['test1','test2','test3'];
    disable() {
        this.isTooltipDisabled = true;
        this.isDisabled = true;
    }

    showList():string{

      let temp:string = ``;
      for(let code of this.codes){
        temp+=`<span>${code}</span><br>`;
      }

      return temp;
    }

}
```

**component HTML:**

```
<h2>PrimeNG Issue</h2>

<div>     
    <div [pTooltip]="showList()" [escape]="false" tooltipPosition="bottom">This is sample</div>

</div>
```

I have used property binding with pTooltip to show the return value of method `showList()` as HTML string.

Here is a working example :

[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/yTRoHvao31nSQyGEsKM0?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks Niladri, it's perfect. Better than my workaround : <div pTooltip="Liste: <span>{{codes.join('<br>'}}</span>" [escape]="false"></div>

Comment: How can I copy text the content of PrimeNG Tooltip? becaue when I am hovering mouse on tooltip, it automatically gets hide. Is there any solution you know?

Comment: @techguy copy the contents using windows copy to clipboard function.You can do that on mousehover event `(mouseover)='over()'`

Comment: @Niladri but still is there any way to keep sticky on mouse hover, and it should get hidden when we mouseout?