# Asynchronously loaded tooltips in Angular 6/PrimeNG

Tags: angular, primeng

I have an Angular 6 application that displays a grid of objects of different type. I'd like that, when a user moves the mouse over an object for a while (300ms for example), a tooltip appeared with more information about that object. I'm using PrimeNG UI library, that comes with a handy tooltip component, that can be used like this:

```
<div class="divObject" 
  pTooltip="<h2>Object info</h2><p>Here would go the object information</p>" [escape]="false"
  tooltipPosition="top">
    <!-- OBJECT NAME -->
</div>
```

The problem I have is that, to get the info about the object, I need to make a call to the DB server. So, I considered creating a pipe to get the data, and use it like:

```
<div class="divObject"
  pTooltip="{{ object | getInfoPipe }}" [escape]="false"
  tooltipPosition="top">
  <!-- OBJECT NAME -->
</div>
```

But, I've read that using pipes for API calls is a really bad idea because it can be called tens of times, so it would overload the server rapidly.

How could I achieve what I need? (Not necessarily using the PrimeNG tooltip component, I'm open to other alternatives)

Thanks!

Comment: Hope this link help you: [Primeng pTooltip loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49755193/primeng-ptooltip-loop?answertab=active#answer-49756070)

Comment: Hi! I've checked the link but I can't use the example in it because it would do as many API calls as objects in the grid, and I only want to call to the API for the hovered object. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

There are different approaches to this.

You can make the pipe execute the call only one for a given input by making it pure: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39285608/4125622

You could make an interceptor cache HTTP-requests and respond to same requests with the same response without calling the actual backend: https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses

But you are right, both approaches are a bit hacky.

I would bind the tooltip-info to a variable (like `object.tooltipText`, see example below) and disable the tooltip as long as it is undefined (not loaded from server yet). In this case you would need to trigger the HTTP-call yourself; you could do this by calling httpClient in the `ngOnInit` of the component which holds the element with the specific tooltip. If you use Redux, you would only dispatch an action and the reducer would update your object like this:

```
object.mainText: "click me",
object.tooltipText: undefined
```

becomes

```
object.mainText: "click me",
object.tooltipText: "for more information see example.org"
```

As for the tooltip-recommendation, I recommend ngx-bootstrap one. The lib is a bit more active and the developers are not as rude as the prime-ng ones (who are known for closing issues without reasons).